# MySQL query sometimes run slow, sometimes fast

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, percona, xtradb

I am having problem with this simple MySQL query:

```
select sender as id from message where status=1 and recipient=1
```

where sender table has multi millions of rows.

When I run this on SequelPro, it runs really slow for the first time, ~4 seconds or more, and the next execution it run really fast, ~0.018 seconds. However, if I run again after couple of minutes, it will do the same thing again.

I tried to use SQL_NO_CACHE, and it still gives me the same result.

The DB engine is innoDB, and the DB is MySQL Percona XtraDB cluster. 
Here is the explain results:

```
|id|select_type|table  |type|possible_keys         |key |key_len|ref            |row   |Extra
| 1|SIMPLE     |message|ref |recipient,status, sent|sent|12     |const,const    |2989   |NULL
```

"sent" is an index of multi-column of (recipient, status).
Does anyone has any idea to fix this problem?

Thank you.

**Added** (from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE 'message' (
    'id' int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'sender' bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    'recipient' bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    'status' int(5) NOT NULL, 
    'date' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'), 
    KEY 'id' ('id'), 
    KEY 'recipient' ('recipient'), 
    KEY 'sender' ('sender'), 
    KEY 'date' ('date'), 
    KEY 'status' ('status'), 
    KEY 'sent' ('status','recipient')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=90224500 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You can use the limit in your mysql query. e.g `select sender as id from message where status=1 and recipient=1 LIMIT 10` OR you can also use the offset like `select sender as id from message where status=1 and recipient=1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15`

Comment: @SanjayChaudhari Thanks for the reply. However, I want to get all of the results from the table. That's why I don't use LIMIT. But I will try to loop the query for every 100 records and see if it makes any difference even though it's not a good solution since in the future the record will grow.

Comment: See if your index is used properly. Also, backup the table and re-create it. Then import the records from the dump once. Scattered records may come together and boos up performance a little.

Answer (score 2):

Those symptoms point to caching issues.  I don't mean the "Query cache", but rather the Engine's cache.

How big is the table?  How big are all the the active tables?

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

I suspect the buffer_pool is a lot smaller than the table(s), and a lot of stuff is going on.  Hence, the query's blocks get bumped out of RAM, necessitating a few dozen reads to bring them back in.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of available RAM.

**More** (based on `CREATE TABLE`)

The "covering" `INDEX(status, recipient, sender)` will be faster -- it won't have to bounce over to the data; the query can be done entirely in the index.

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a key, so `INDEX(id)` is redundant and can be `DROPped`.

A `KEY` that is a prefix of another key is redundant.  I am referring to `(status)` in your current `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: the table is about 80 million rows. The value of innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2GB, and the RAM size is 8GB. In the past, I have configured the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5GB, but when I tested a lot of query requests, like about 1000 requests/second, MySQL suddenly died. But when I changed it to 2GB, I never experience MySQL dying on its own.

Comment: Do not draw a big list at once. You can often see MySQL server go e away error when querying too fast, multiple times. Second immediate query is likely to run faster possibly due to hard disk performance where the HDD head is very close to the data to read next.

Comment: @BimalPoudel I tried to use LIMIT in the query like this: `select sender as id from message where status=1 and recipient=1 LIMIT 0,100`, but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I'm missing some thing subtle.

Comment: @RickJames Here is the "SHOW CREATE TABLE message"

`CREATE TABLE 'message' (
  'id' int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'sender' bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  'recipient' bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  'status' int(5) NOT NULL,
  'date' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 'id' ('id'),
  KEY 'recipient' ('recipient'),
  KEY 'sender' ('sender'),
  KEY 'date' ('date'),
  KEY 'status' ('status'),
  KEY 'sent' ('status','recipient')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=90224500 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: Give that 3-column index a try.

Comment: @RickJames What do you mean by "A `KEY` that is a prefix of another key is redundant"? Also, why do I need to index "sender" since it's not in the `WHERE` clause? But I'll give this a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: `sender` makes it a "covering" index.

Comment: `INDEX(a), INDEX(a,b)` -- there is no need for the former, since the latter can handle, say `WHERE a = 123` even though `b` is not mentioned.